# Why won't my tank rotate properly?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I have a moving tank: http://www.exeneva.com/html5/movingTankExample/

The tank uses a finite state machine for the direction it is facing, with default set to "up":

```
var tankDir = "up";
```

The function that handles the rotation is below:

```
function dirTank(dir) {
  switch (dir) {
    case "up":
      if (tankDir == "right") {
        rotationAngle += -90;
      } else if (tankDir == "down") {
        rotationAngle += 180;
      } else if (tankDir == "left") {
        rotationAngle += 90;
      }
      break;
    case "down":
      if (tankDir == "up") {
        rotationAngle += 180; 
      } else if (tankDir == "right") {
        rotationAngle += 90;
      } else if (tankDir == "left") {
        rotationAngle += -90;
      }
      break;
    case "left":
      if (tankDir == "up") {
        rotationAngle += -90;
      } else if (tankDir == "right") {
        rotationAngle += 180;
      } else if (tankDir == "down") {
        rotationAngle += 90;
      }
      break;
    case "right":
      if (tankDir == "up") {
        rotationAngle += 90;
      } else if (tankDir == "down") {
        rotationAngle += -90;
      } else if (tankDir == "left") {
        rotationAngle += 180;
      }
      break;
  }
  tankDir = dir;
  rotationAngle %= 360;
}
```

The tank rendering code in drawScreen looks like this:

```
  // Draw the tank
  context.save();
  context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // identity matrix
  context.translate(tankX + tileWidth/2, tankY + tileHeight/2);
  rotationAngle = rotationAngle * Math.PI/180;
  context.rotate(rotationAngle);
  context.drawImage(tileSheet, tankSourceX, tankSourceY, tileWidth, tileHeight, -tileWidth/2, -tileHeight/2, tileWidth, tileHeight);
  context.restore();
```

But the tank seems to turn and then suddenly revert back to its original direction. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: It doesn't really seem the problem is in that piece of code.

Comment: Your tank is somewhat uncontrollable

Comment: Lieutenant Gruber will be pleased to know his little tank can rotate now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rotationAngle` should be kept in another variable and all your assignments should be changed to either increase or decrease the current angle, e.g.

```
rotationAngle += 90; // turn right
rotationAngle += 180; // reverse direction
```

After those changes, you need to normalize the angle:

```
rotationAngle %= 360;
```

**Update**

```
Make sure to not overwrite the `rotationAngle` later in the code when you convert from degrees to radians.

rotationAngle = rotationAngle * Math.PI/180;
```

Should become:

```
rotationAngleRad = rotationAngle * Math.PI/180;
```

Then use `rotationAngleRad` in the `.rotate()` call.

Comment: Updated, but still not entirely functioning.

Comment: @YangPulse what does that mean? what are you seeing?

Comment: I updated the code based on your comments, but I'm seeing the same thing I have been seeing.

Comment: @YangPulse If you have updated the code, please update the question so all can see. thanks

Comment: Done. Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you need to change the rotation every time you redraw the canvas not just the first time.

Comment: @YangPulse what about during the drawScreen function that gets called during your timeout?

Comment: Ah, that's where it's at. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Save the rotation as a global variable and then and then add the code to drawScreen to draw the tank accordingly.